# Exibir e ocultar campos de formulário do tipo radio

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo um formulário com dois `inputs` do tipo `radio`, um com valor pessoa física e outro jurídica. Quando um é selecionado, os campos a serem preenchidos são diferentes do outro (principalmente no PJ), por isso gostaria de saber uma maneira bem prática de exibir e ocultar os campos do formulário ao selecionar uma das opções.

Comment: Tu pode colocar 2 divs, pf e pj, com display none e quando o usuário clicar em um dos radio's ele seta a display block de uma dessas divs

Comment: Javascript puro ou algum framework como Angular? Você precisa dar mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer algo assim, utilizando apenas Javascript:

```js
function tipoPessoaSel() {
  var pf = document.getElementById("opt-pf").checked;
  if (pf) {
    document.getElementById("pf").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("pj").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pf").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pj").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Cadastro</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="opt-pf">Pessoa Física</label>
    <input id="opt-pf" checked="checked" type="radio" name="TipoPessoa" onclick="tipoPessoaSel();" />&nbsp;
    <label for="opt-pj">Pessoa Jurídica</label>
    <input id="opt-pj" type="radio" name="TipoPessoa" onclick="tipoPessoaSel();" />
  </div>
  <div id="pf">
    <div>
      <label for="cpf">Cpf</label>
      <input id="cpf" type="text" name="Cpf" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <br />Outros campos Pessoa Física...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="pj" style="display: none;">

    <div>
      <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
      <input id="cnpj" type="text" name="Cnpj" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <br />Outros campos Pessoa Jurídica
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```